# Viewing AIC for many variables with proper header

Tags: r, combinations, lm

I'm pretty new in R and i'm stuck with one problem.
I've already found how to create many linear models at once, i made a function that counts AIC for each `lm`, but I cannot display this function with header that will show the name of the `lm`. I mean i want to get a data frame with header e.g. `lm(a~b+c, data=data)`, and the AIC result for this `lm`.
Here's what i already wrote (with big help from stackoverflow, of course)

```
vars <- c("azot_stand", "przeplyw", "pH", "twardosc", "fosf_stand", "jon_stand", "tlen_stand", "BZO_stand", "spadek_stand")  
N <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  
COMB <- sapply(N, function(m) combn(x=vars[1:8], m))  
COMB2 <- list()  
k=0  
for(i in seq(COMB)){  
  tmp <- COMB[[i]]  
  for(j in seq(ncol(tmp))){  
    k <- k + 1  
    COMB2[[k]] <- formula(paste("azot_stand", "~", paste(tmp[,j], collapse=" + ")))  
  }  
}  
res <- vector(mode="list", length(COMB2))  
for(i in seq(COMB2)){  
  res[[i]] <- lm(COMB2[[i]], data=s)  
}  

aic <- vector(mode="list", length(COMB2))  
d=0  
for(i in seq(res)){  
  aic[[i]] <- AIC(res[[i]])  
}  

View(aic)       
show(COMB2)
```

I guess that i miss something in the `aic`, but don't know what...

Answer (score 1):

With `formula` you can obtain the formula of a regression model. Since you want to store the formula with the AIC, I would create a `data.frame` containing both:

```
aic <- data.frame(model = character(length(res)), aic = numeric(length(res)), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
for(i in seq(res)){  
  aic$model[i] <- deparse(formula(res[[i]]), width.cutoff = 500)
  aic$aic[i] <- AIC(res[[i]])  
}
```

Normally you would use `format` to convert a formula to a character. However, for long formulas this results in multiple lines. Therefore, I use `deparse` (which is also used by `format`) and passed it the `width.cutoff` argument.

You cannot use `res[[i]]$call` as this is always equal to `lm(formula = COMB2[[i]], data = s)`.

**Other suggestions**

The first part of your code can be simplified. I would write something like:

```
s <- attitude
vars <- names(attitude)[-1]
yvar <- names(attitude)[1]

models <- character(0)
for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
  comb <- combn(vars, i)
  models <- c(models, 
    paste(yvar, " ~ ", apply(comb, 2, paste, collapse=" + ")))
}

res <- lapply(models, function(m) lm(as.formula(m), data = s))
```

It is shorter and also has the advantage that magical constants such as the `8` and `azot_stand` are defined outside the main code and can easily be modified.

I also noticed that you use `azot_stand` both as target variable and `predictor` (it is also part of `vars`). I don't think you will want to do that.

Comment: I worked on this and now the first part of the code is the same I had, but the `aic` works properly only the way you did it. Also you were right about the azot_stand predictor - I deleted it from the `vars`. Now it works just fine. Thanks!